# Connecting to the device via zkemkeeper.dll WITH PASSWORD in C# .net

Tags: c#, sdk, windows, biometrics

I have to implement a biometric system. Im using ZKTeco LP600 time attendance device and ZKTeco SDK (ZKemKeeper.dll) here its the situation:

When I try to connect to device with no security password(the one who configure in the device > menu > communication > security > 6 digit Password ) I achieve it without any trouble.

But when I put some password things go wrong...I recive the error -6

Im using: bool isConn= axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(devIP,4370);

Comment: Your question is to specific, if you add a password you probably have to authenticate first... where is the documentation, mostlikly there is an overload for username or password or authentication method

Comment: @Robert K did you ever find a solution to it?

Comment: @SafiMustafa Yes. Let me post the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer to my own question if someone need the info in the future. After checking the class dictionary (Which I found in a remote place in the zk page) there's a method call `SetCommPassword(int password)` which you must set before use the Connect_Net method. Theres many strange things in this dll and im still trying to understand some....

Comment: What if there is no password on device?

Comment: How did you find the meaning of -6. There is nothing written about this error in SDK manual. I am getting -7 error.

Comment: When there's no password on  device you doesnt need to call this method.  But theres some bug in the firmware (at least in mine).. when you save a password in the device and after you try to erase you  symply can't so.... you put a "0" in the device and  you cant connect without  setcommPassword method (but its not recomended)

Comment: @SafiMustafa Did you manage to find meaning for errorcode -7 ?